# init a aptos wallet with mnemonic by python

Tags: python, wallet, aptos

I only known its about bip39 to generate a mnemonic and  use bip44 to get a hd wallet,
the **aptos** derivation path is **"m/44'/637'/0'/0'/0'"** and privdev is **"0x8000027d"**
thanks
[bip44](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md)

Comment: i made it，https://github.com/satisfywithmylife/aptos_wallet_mnemonic